# Bash find if all env variables are declared, by variable name

Tags: bash

I'm having issues with the below script. It should exit only if there is not a variable set by that name.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

echo 'START: env_vars_config'

required_var(){
  VARIABLE=$1
  echo "detecting if $VARIABLE exists"
  echo ${!VARIABLE}
  if [ -z ${!VARIABLE}+x ]; then
    echo "${VARIABLE} was defined"
  else
    echo "Need to set environment var $VARIABLE" && exit 1;
  fi
}

# these are required variables to deploy
required_var MONGO_URL
required_var AWS_REGION
required_var AUTOSCALING_GROUP_NAME
required_var LATEST_STABLE_COMMIT
required_var ENV_FILE
required_var DEPLOY_FILE
required_var POSTMAN_ENVIRONMENT_UID
required_var POSTMAN_COLLECTION_UID
required_var POSTMAN_API_KEY
required_var MANDRILL_KEY
required_var SERVER_SECRET
required_var S3_BUCKET
required_var ELASTIC_URL
required_var ELASTIC_PASSWORD
required_var ELASTIC_PREFIX


echo 'END: env_vars_config'
```

Right now this script always exits on the first check `MONGO_URL` however I know this is variable set and is a string.

- What would a check for `unset` look like?
- What would a check for `unset` or `empty string` look like?

**FIXED**
2 issues, firstly the `+` symbol at the end of the if statement was a typo.
Secondly I had the order of the if statement backwards.

```
  if [ -z "${!VARIABLE}" ]; then
    echo "Need to set environment var $VARIABLE" && exit 1;
  else
    echo "${VARIABLE} was defined"
  fi
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is:

```
if [ -z ${!VARIABLE}+x ]; then
    echo "${VARIABLE} was defined"
else
    echo "Need to set environment var $VARIABLE" && exit 1;
fi
```

`-z` "string" is true if string is empty.

`+x` is a typo? You do not need that.

Working condition:

```
if [ -z "${!VARIABLE}" ]; then
    echo "Need to set environment var $VARIABLE" && exit 1;
else
    echo "${VARIABLE} was defined"
fi
```

Comment: Unfortunately I receive similar results with or without the `+` I've updated my question with the output of your recommendation.

Comment: @LessQuesar Notice that @V-Mark also switched the `if` statements. `-z` looks if the string is empty. If this is true then exit. You do it the other way round in your script.

Comment: @duenni You're right, the order i had was backwards.

Comment: You should put double-quotes around `${!VARIABLE}` -- without them, you'll get syntax errors if the variable contains multiple words (or a wildcard that matches multiple files, or...).

Comment: True. I modified `${!VARIABLE}` to `"${!VARIABLE}"`

Comment: does "+x" have any meaning?